# Build system that can use dependencies from multiple repost

Tags: maven, gradle, ant

I have worked as a Software Engineer for Amazon for many year, but have recently decided to move to another company. At Amazon there is a custom build system, called brazil.

The way it worked was that i would define a workspace, and then define what packages i where to use for my development. An an example: Package A, is dependent on B, C, and D. When i created my workspace i would specify that i need to have A and B locally.

That following folder structor would be created:

```
myServiceAWorkspace
 - .workspaceConfig
 - A/
 - A/src
 - A/tst
 - A/.packageConfig
 - B/
 - B/src
 - B/tst
 - B/.packageConfig
```

`.packageConfig` contained information on the dependencies and how to build the project, much like a `build.gradle`

If i where to go to the A folder and run our build command, would it build the A package with B from the local workspace, but will used C and D from our repository. (Any dependencies from B would also be used from our repository, unless they are checked out in the local workspace)

I found this very powerful as made sharing packages between different services, among other things, very easy.

If have been looking for a build system that works like this, but without luck. Are there any build system that can do this or are there a way i can make Gradle or Maven work like this?

Comment: For what exactly you are looking? In Maven, you can group different projects as "Modules" into a multi-module project and then build them together. You can reference jars from other projects through the Maven coordinates.

Comment: What you have defined `.packageConfig` is the `pom.xml` as equivalent in Maven. And what you describe is a multi module build which has a root `myServiceWorkspace` which should contain a pom.xml which lists the modules it contains `A` and `B`. Each module should also have a pom file which describes which dependencies it has maybe external or other modules. If you build such project you build from the root location and maven handles to define the correct order to built. The location for source code is src/main/java and for unit-/integration tests is src/test/java plus package names etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the organization has created a build system for a certain need, by the way Maven and Gradle follow the principle of convention over configuration. I would suggest particularly in your case to use [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/) an old build system but it is great. If you want you can also use [Apache Ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to customize your build based upon the need. Again it may not satisfy your exact requirements which you mentioned but at least you will be able do so. I think it is recommended to follow Maven or Gradle where everybody can use with ease.

As JF Meier Sir suggested, you can create multi module maven or gradle project for more granular approach.

Comment: Any suggestion will help me to improve.

Comment: I don't think one should recommend Ant as build system any more.If you want to "do your own thing", i.e. construct a custom way of building, I would go with Gradle.

Comment: I want to know whether it is possible to change the build phases in existing gradle system, if you have some example, please pass on to me, I need to use in some system for a custom requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something similar in Gradle with the help of [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.2/userguide/composite_builds.html#header).